# Fallback to Gnome classic desktop Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, gnome-classic

I'm using Ubuntu for a while and experienced many bugs in Unity and also it kills productivity. I recently checked BackTrackR3 release which is built on Gnome2.3. But, unfortunately that is available only with Ubuntu 10.04 which has got its support period over.

So, Can I able to switch back to Gnome 2.32 as shown  in the figure below from Ubuntu 14.04?

[image]

If so, which is the best flavor I can download? Ubuntu Unity or Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: Isnt this the same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop?rq=1

Comment: Heh. It's interesting that you use my screenshot that way. It was intended to demonstrate that the Gnome Panel 3 desktop is almost identical to the Gnome 2 desktop. The screenshot is from Ubuntu 11.10 and is the Gnome 3 version of the traditional desktop.

Comment: ha ha lol. I wanted to show an environment like gnome 2 and I don't had one - so I googled and got this image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found gnome-flashback-session which provides both Compiz and Metacity environment. Installation guide is [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/how-to-install-and-tweak-gnome.html). You can see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I installed gnome-session-flashback, but I don't see any options on the login screen :(

Comment: There will an icon next to your password field. Click that and you'll get a list of installed DE's

Comment: Right... but the Ubuntu/Gnome logo was just completely missing from the login screen. Fortunately I got it to appear, by installing `gnome-panel` (apparently it was not included as a dependency of `gnome-fallback-session`).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Ubuntu Gnome, it has the Gnome 3 shell and the fallback (the old one). Also you can install Matte, Cinnamon, etc.

Comment: Can I switch it back to the environment as like Gnome 2.32?

Comment: @Gowtham Try Mate instead if you want Gnome2 feel. It's a fork for Gnome2 that runs on newer kernels. [Check here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-mate-18-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: YEs, i would go with Mate like Arda said.