# Windows Ubuntu Bash GUI

Tags: gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed bash in windows 10 insider preview. But gedit is not working. I also use software R for my statistical work, its lot of options like 'plot' also not working. Is it the fact that no program like gedit can be opened through bash I mean wont that support any GUI ?

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu on Windows does not support the X11 window system, which is needed for graphical applications in Linux. [People have managed to use Xming to get things to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4ea4w4/fyi_you_can_run_gui_linux_apps_from_bash/) (with Cygwin's X suggested as an alternative), but it's not very stable. YMMV. It's not official, and if anything breaks, don't ask here.

Comment: So, is it official that windows wont support GUI or in future stable version they will support?

Comment: All official mentions of this have solely been about command line programs. No MS blog or announcement has mentioned GUI programs. And [Scott Hanselman](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/717640932812689408) says that GUI is "absolutely not the use case". Make of that what you will.

Comment: @muru Have you evaluated at other x-windows packages for windows like [vcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) or [x2go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik6XCtkqXdQ)?

Answer (score 4):

Although WSL does not include X-Windows, you can run a X-Windows in the Windows Operating System and [display the linux applications in the same desktop](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-x-on-wsl). There are many [tutorials](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx) and [blog entries](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-a-pretty-and-usable-terminal-emulator-for-wsl/) you may check.

**Running Applications**

- I use [VcSrv Windows X Server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/), but you can use the old [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) or the [Cygwin X Server](http://x.cygwin.com/). For VcXrv, you only need to download and install the software.
- After starting the X-Windows, you must instruct Linux to use the desktop

  ```
  $ export DISPLAY=:0
  ```
- Then, you can install and run linux applications that use a graphical user interface. For instance, to run `xeyes` you may run

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install x11-apps
  $ xeyes
  ```

**Running a Unix Desktop**

Ubuntu uses Unity or GNOME as a desktop. There are some people that have been trying to [run a Unix desktop in the WSL](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-run-run-the-native-ubuntu-desktop-on-windows-10/). The instructions are also included in [an issue in the Github](https://github.com/microsoft/bashonwindows/issues/637).

- Run the X-Windows in a standalone window to avoid confusion with the Windows desktop. Run the `XLaunch` windows program and select the "One large window" or the "Fullscreen" mode. You must close any other running X-Windows.
- Install the desktop packages.

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Use the local X-Windows and configure the compiz windows manager

  ```
  $ export DISPLAY=:0
  $ ccsm
  ```
- Run the desktop

  ```
  $ compiz
  ```

There are some message errors caused by some initialization not performed by the WSL. I had problems with the graphical acceleration in some packages. You may try the [GNOME classic desktop flashback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452665/fallback-to-gnome-classic-desktop-ubuntu-14-04) instead the default one.